# Understanding properties of Boundaries

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm having trouble answering this question in regards to boundaries.

(a) Let (X; d) be a metric space and E is a subset of X. Is it possible to have bd(E) \ E = the empty set? If yes give an example. If not give a
counterexample.

By definition, I thought a boundary point had to have an epsilon neighbourhood around it that shared some points with both E and E'. However, I feel like anything can happen in metric space, I just cannot think of an example. Any help to get my brain going on this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Try $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $E = \{\text{one point}\}$.

Comment: Let's assume that one point is 5. We're looking for a bd(E) such that bd(E) is disjoint from E, and does not contain 5. So is the boundary of the singleton set {5} just the rest of the Real Numbers, excluding 5, aka E'? In my head I'm picturing the boundary of {5} to be an arbitrary epsilon neighbourhood around the point 5 in the Reals, but maybe that's wrong?

Comment: You do not seem to be applying the definition of $bd(E)$ that you wrote in your question. The set $bd(E)$ is defined to be the set of points $x \in X$ such that **each** neighborhood of $x$ shares points with both $E$ and $E'$. **Each** neighborhood of $5$ shares points with both $\{5\}$ and $\mathbb{R}-\{5\}$, so $5 \in bd\{5\}$. **Some** neighborhood of $7$ does not share any point with $\{5\}$, so $7 \not\in bd\{5\}$.

Comment: Thank you, you've cleared up my self-induced confusion. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If E is closed, then bd(E)\E is empty, as bd(E) is contained in E

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(0,1)$ in the real numbers, usual metric.